# OCR in android Studio errors after building ndk from command promt for tess-two & eyes-two Tesseract

Tags: android, android-ndk, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to do OCR demo in android Studio using tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/840623/Android-Character-Recognition  and been following RmTheis's guidelines and after this built ndk from command prompt for tess-two and eyes-two.But still Getting errors?
Error >>>
Updates an Android project "must already have an AndroidManifest.xml ",where could I have made mistake although I am following every steps.
my output in Command promt is shown in the image.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android update project --target 1 --path C:\ .....\tess-two

Comment: This is how i found a solution.